# Is there a numeric version of SUBSTR in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This may be a complete noob question. I have spent hours looking for a solution but haven't found one...

I am trying to capture the first digit of each number in a column of numbers. For example:

```
173563 = 1
247309 = 2
653638 = 6
```

etc

I know that I could do this using SUBSTR if the value were a string but that doesn't work for numbers. I have a work around but there must be a better way than how I'm currently doing it.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
with
-- Convert to string and get the first character
stage1 as (
SELECT
number
, SUBSTR(CAST(number AS STRING), 1, 1) AS cut_off
FROM my_table
),

-- Convert back to a numeric value
stage2 as (
SELECT
number
, CAST(cut_off AS NUMERIC) AS cut_off,
FROM stage1
)

select
number,
cut_off
from stage2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below "trick"

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 173563 number union all
  select 247309 union all
  select 653638 
)
select number, left('' || number, 1) cut_off
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

Obviously, such a trick allows you to use any string function to meet your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one expression:

```
CAST(LEFT(CAST(number AS STRING), 1) as int64)
```

If the length of the number is always 6 digits, you can use arithmetic:

```
FLOOR(number / 100000)
```

Or:

```
DIV(number, 100000)
```